# Div float next to non float div

Tags: html, css

I have a container div for the main content but am trying to have a sidebar float to the left of it. For example (http://www.bureautonic.com/en/) the menu button.

This is the code

```css
.main-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      height: 500px;

    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .slider {
      display: block;
      width: 940px;
      height: 500px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      float: none;
    }
    .img {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .tagline {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;
      width: 332px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: 1em 3em;
      border: 1px solid white;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0px) translate(0px, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0px) translate(0px, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, 0px) translate(0px, -50%);
      font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: none;
    }
    .header {
      margin-top: 33px;
      margin-bottom: -61px;
    }
    .brand {
      font-family: Cardo, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="w-section container">
    <div class="w-container header">
      <h1 class="brand">The One And Only</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w-container main-wrapper">
      <div data-animation="outin" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1" data-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-hide-arrows="1" class="w-slider slider">
        <div class="w-slider-mask">
          <div class="w-slide slide">
            <div class="tagline">
              <h1>Marc Cain</h1>
              <h3>F/W 2015-16</h3>
            </div>
            <img width="846" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/567a26541a69a693654038a1/567b15da06a9675444fc740d_marc_cain_campaign.jpg" class="img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
          <div class="w-icon-slider-left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
          <div class="w-icon-slider-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-slider-nav"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm using webflow and uploaded the site for you guys http://the-one-and-only.webflow.io/

I originally tried making another absolute div with a set width and 100% height, but the menu button wasn't relative to the  main container. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the markup of the menu button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a look, it mimics what http://www.bureautonic.com/en/ has for their menu

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu-container').click(
    function() {
      ToggleMenu();
    }
  );
});

function ToggleMenu() {
  var $menu = $('#menu');
  var newleft = +$menu.css('left').replace('px', '') <= -150 ? '0' : '-300px';
  $('#menu').css('left', newleft);




}
```

```css
#menu,
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
#menu {
  transition: left 1s;
  left: -300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#menu-label {
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-container">
  <div id="menu-label">
    This is my Menu Label
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  This is the content
  <div id="menu">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

#### For the sliding menu

The basic concept is a **parent** `div` with `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden` , and a **child** div with `position:absolute`, beginning with a negative `left` equal to the width of the `div`

I used the css `transition` property for the smooth slide effect

### Edit:

#### For the left aligned & rotated menu label

This effect is created with a combination of several properties.

My code block has been updated with the appropriate css.

> See here http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/79/ (not my fiddle) for alterations
>   to the `css` if you need to have a dynamic height

Comment: Sorry, may of not been clear and is my fault. But i'm having issues placing the actual "Menu" text next to the content container.

Comment: @DillonRaphael no problem, I've updated my answer to include this. Click the yello menu  label on the left to toggle the menu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to float a menu to left of the main content, you need to firstly create the menu element that you want to be the menu (obviously), then float it to the left with `float: left`. e.g.

HTML

```
    <div class="floated-menu">
        Menu
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .floated-menu {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

Then you have to float the main content container as well. .e.g

```
    .container {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

I could be wrong, but I believe if you don't float both the items, the normal (non-floated context) behaviour of the container divs `display: block;`  property kicks in and it will move down the page to the next "line". Which is weird because all items next to something thats floated should lose their display block behaviour and sit next to the floated item - i.e. float was originally intended to make block type headings and paragraphs sit next to pictures like in a magazine or newspaper, but yep, welcome to the world of CSS - you fill find many nonsensical  things like this.
Also, the combined width of both floated elements `border box` (the widest and largest of the boxes that an element is contained in) cannot be wider than their parent element - other wise the second element will drop down to the next line - which actually does make sense. I have reduced the sizes for you in my demo, but you will have to manage that as you build your page.
You also need to remember that, by default the browser uses the 
"content-box" [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property. from the docs

**content-box**

> This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width
>   and height properties are measured including only the content, but not
>   the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be
>   outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply
>   {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box
>   {width: 370px;}

Here is a **demo** - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyKyVV?editors=110